# Comparison of boiling points of n-propyl chlorine and ethyl iodide

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point

I know that boiling point of alkyl halide is proportional to the length of the alkyl group, and that the order of BP is RI > RBr > RCl > RF for an alkyl group R. But which of the factors is dominant?

Comment: It depends on occasion, in this case iodide has higher boiling point.

Comment: Does it depend on the occasion? Perhaps some investigation of simultaneously removing a CH2 and converting a chlorine to an iodide could be investigated as a function of alkyl group. First step is to generalize the question, then determine analysis approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [online resource](https://www.slideserve.com/duc/alkyl-halides) I found, it is clear that the boiling point of $\ce{C2H5I}$ is more than that of $\ce{C3H7Cl}$.

[image]

I wouldn't draw any general conclusions from this since the values are comparable and so the trend may change when comparing branched/ring hydrocarbon moieties. This trend also works out when comparing fluorides and chlorides. However, this trend is reversed when comparing chlorides and bromides, probably, because of the addition of d-subshell.

**Edit**:
Although I have not referenced the CRC handbook (since I do not have the handbook), I did find more evidence regarding the reported values [here](http://organicchemistrystructures.weebly.com/alcohols-haloalkanes-carboxylic-acids.html) and [here](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/chemistry/organic-chemistry-ii/alkyl-halides/introduction-to-alkyl-halides). You will also be able to cross-verify the data at [ChemLibreTexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Alkyl_Halides/Properties_of_Alkyl_Halides/Haloalkanes).

I also checked some values with Wikipedia and the corresponding first search engine result and the values seem to match.

**Edit**: While doing further reading from Wikipedia, I found that, besides dipole moment, boiling points are also related to molecular masses. I drew this graph showing the variation of boiling point (on $y$-axis) with the mass of the haloalkanes (on $x$-axis)

[image]

Comment: An expanded trend could also count as semi-answer, but the data at least needs to be presented 1. in a readable form as a properly formatted table with data sources and units and not a low-quality screenshot, and 2. from an authoritative source, which a random PPT file from the internet is not. Also, both chemical formulas and symbols for orbitals are upright.

Comment: @andselisk okay noted

Comment: That's great. So, when are you going to fix the answer? We can help with the formatting, but the data source is something you need to sort out yourself.

Comment: @andselisk i'll fix the data source and formatting by tomorrow, quick question: do we accept wikipedia?

Comment: Strictly speaking, [Wikipedia is not a reliable source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_is_not_a_reliable_source), but it the absence of other sources it is at least trackable in most cases where the data comes from. I'd probably use *CRC Handbook of chemistry and physics* for data.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, but citing two other obscure websites doesn't help. Why not search for the source of the table, *reformat it as text so that it is searchable* (not as an image), and *cite the textbook it has been taken from*? These websites ripped the table 6-2 from Vollhardt's *Organic Chemistry* 2014, so cite the origin and break the circle of copypasting stuff without proper attribution.

Comment: @andselisk I don't have Vollhardt's book either. Though I wanted to ask, what are your thoughts on the boiling point vs. molecular mass of the haloalkanes graph?

Answer (score 0):

Two types of intermolecular forces influence the boiling points of alkyl halides. London forces and dipole dipole interaction. In case of alkyl halides the dipole dipole interaction has a smaller influence when compared with the influence of London forces. Now, London forces are surface attractions, arising from coordinated temporary dipoles and molecules with larger surface area have larger London attractions so resulting in higher boiling points. So that's why the boiling point of Ethyl iodide is about 72°C and that of Propyl chloride is about 47°C. And this is also reason that for halides boiling point order is
R-F < R-Cl < R-Br < R-I.