# Why is the boiling point of a iodoalkane greater than that of the corresponding fluoroalkane?

Tags: physical-chemistry, halides, boiling-point

Why is the boiling point of [ethyl iodide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethyl_iodide) (b.p. 72 °C) higher than the boiling point of [ethyl fluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroethane) (b.p. −37 °C) even though the dipole–dipole interaction should be better in $\ce{C2H5F}?$ Is it because of higher molecular mass of iodine?

Comment: [Related - Comparison of boiling points of n-propyl chlorine and ethyl iodide](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/166107/comparison-of-boiling-points-of-n-propyl-chlorine-and-ethyl-iodide/166113)

Comment: The molecular weight difference is significant.

Comment: Because given enough polariz-able electrons dispersion forces beat polarity. And most things have enough polariz-able electrons.

Answer (score 3):

The way in which intermolecular forces (IMF) are taught can sometimes be confusing.  Students are generally taught that dispersion forces (London dispersion, van der Waals) are the weakest IMF, with by dipole-dipole interactions being stronger and then hydrogen bonding being the strongest.

This is true for **individual** interactions, but since properties like melting point and boiling point are affected by the sum of all the interactions between molecules, the situation is not as straightforward as that.

As a rule of thumb, when two molecules have similar molar masses (about ${\pm}$10 g/mol) to each other, the more polar molecule will have the higher boiling point.

For example, consider ethane, fluoromethane and iodomethane.

|  | Ethane | Fluoromethane | Iodomethane |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Formula | $\ce{C2H6}$ | $\ce{CH3F}$ | $\ce{CH3I}$ |
| Molar mass (g/mol) | 30.07 | 34.03 | 141.94 |
| Dipole moment (Debye) | 0 | 1.847 | 1.620 |
| Boiling Point (${^o}$C) | -89 | -78.4 | 42 |

If we compare ethane and fluoromethane, they have similar molar masses, so the dispersion interactions for each molecule can considered similar.  That being the case, the difference in boiling point results from the presence of dipole-dipole interactions.

However, if we compare fluoromethane to iodomethane, the difference in the molar masses (really the difference in size between F and I) is the determining factor.  Even though $\ce{CH3F}$ is more polar than $\ce{CH3I}$, it has a lower boiling point.

It's important to realize as well that the difference in polarity between similar haloalkanes is not as dramatic as students are led to think.

|  | $\ce{CH3F}$ | $\ce{CH3Cl}$ | $\ce{CH3Br}$ | $\ce{CH3I}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Molar mass (g/mol) | 34.03 | 50.49 | 94.94 | 141.94 |
| Dipole moment (Debye) | 1.847 | 1.870 | 1.810 | 1.620 |
| Boiling point (${^oC}$) | -78.4 | -24 | 3.56 | 42 |

**References**
Boiling points: Wikipedia
Dipole moments: https://cccbdb.nist.gov/diplistx.asp